# Closing HttpClient version 4.0.3

Tags: java, windows, macos, apache, http

I have an extension to a commercial application that is bundled with version 4.0.3 of httpclient.  If I try and use later versions the extension does not work.  If I use version 4.0.3 in my code it does.  I wish to close down the HttpClient but can not find the mechanism to do this.

My top class is a SwingWorker which is extended by various subclasses depending on the URL being accessed.

```
public class GetPrices extends SwingWorker<List<StockPrice>,Integer> {
private HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
List<StockPrice> lstStock;
MRBDebug objDebug = MRBDebug.getInstance();
public GetPrices (final List<StockPrice> lstStockp) {
    lstStock = lstStockp;
}  
@Override
protected List<StockPrice> doInBackground() throws Exception {
    int iValue = lstStock.size();
    int iProgress = 0;
    int iPrevious = 0;
    for (StockPrice spLine : lstStock) {
        try { 
            GetPrices.failIfInterrupted();
            getData(client, spLine);
            iProgress++;
        }
        catch (IOException a) {
            iProgress++;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException a) {
            iProgress++;            
        }
        int iTemp =iProgress * 100 / iValue;
        setProgress( iTemp);
    }
    return lstStock;
}

// Can safely update the GUI from this method.
@Override
protected void done() {

    List<StockPrice> spListp;
    try {
        // Retrieve the return value of doInBackground.
        lstStock = get();
        setProgress(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // This is thrown if the thread's interrupted.
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // This is thrown if we throw an exception
        // from doInBackground.
    }
}
```

One of the subclasses is:

```
public class GetYahooPrices extends GetPrices{
private MRBDebug objDebug; 
public GetYahooPrices (List<StockPrice> lstStock) {
    super(lstStock);
}
@Override
public void getData(HttpClient client, StockPrice spPrice) throws IOException {
    objDebug = MRBDebug.getInstance();
    String strStock = spPrice.getTicker();
    try {
        URI uri = new URL("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + strStock + "?p=" + strStock).toURI();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
```

I wish to close down the HttpCLient after all calls to the URL have been completed but can not find anything that does this with version 4.0.3. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();` if you want to close all connections immediately in 4.0.3. Please note that you should use the updated version 4.5.5 of Apache HttpClient as your version in use is 8 years old.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as I said in my post the application I am using unfortunately uses 4.0.3,  I have asked them to upgrade but they provide the JRE and the jars so I am stuck until they upgrade.